# permiso denegado en CGI

Tags: javascript, html, c, apache, script

Quiero crear una web dinámica con cgi, pero ni siquiera puedo ejecutar ese echo,alguno sabe el motivio? empece hace 4 días en cgi,soy un completo nobato
,ya le asigné todos los permisos al archivo,apache ya está configurado para ejecutar archivos .cgi pero no logro encontrar la forma de hacer ejecutar ese echo,sería un buen comienzo

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""


echo leo > /home/leonardo/Escritorio/elLeo

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'

echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'
echo '<h1>hola</h1>'
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

```
/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/app1.cgi: 7: /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/app1.cgi: cannot create /home/leonardo/Escritorio/elLeo: Permission denied
```

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 209 nov  7 17:41 app1.cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

**El error que te sale es porque no puede crear el archivo “elLeo“ en la ruta  /home/leonardo/Escritorio/, dale permisos 777, a esa carpeta o quita esa línea y ya te debería de funcionar**

En esta linea

```
echo leo > /home/leonardo/Escritorio/elLeo
```

No estás imprimiendo, lo que estás haciendo es:
crear un archivo llamado "elLeo" en la carpeta "/home/leonardo/Escritorio/" con el contenido de "leo"

OTRA COSA ES:

En apache de le debes de dar permiso a la carpeta cgi-bin para que ejecute los archivos

Para permitir la ejecución de programas CGI para cualquier archivo que acabe en .cgi en directorios de usuario, puedes usar la siguiente configuración:

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

Si quiere designar un subdirectorio cgi-bin dentro de un directorio de usuario en el que todos los ficheros serán tratados como un programa CGI, puede usar lo siguiente:

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html/cgi-bin">
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```

Comment: donde tengo que escribir esto? Options +ExecCGI AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

Comment: En el archivo **httpd.conf** de apache  
   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/es/howto/cgi.html  Ya intentaste hacer la primer parte de la respuesta, la de cambiar los permisos de la carpeta "/home/leonardo/Escritorio/" o sustituir esta ruta por tu www, de apache?